# running into unhandled promise error with inquirer checkbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, inquirerjs

So I'm writing a node CLI application which consists of a card playing game where the user draws 5 cards and then has a choice to get rid of up to 4 cards in his hand.

I am writing this in Javascript and I'm using the following npm modules

- yargs
- inquirer

and I also created a wrapper for the following API http://deckofcardsapi.com/

using inquirer the user can select up to 4 cards from his current to dispose, however I am running into a bit of an issue. I'm not entirely how to pass the user's current hand to the choices array in the inquirer prompt. I've tried a few things but I keep getting the following errors:

> (node:13764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of
>   undefined` 
>  (node:13764) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
>   promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
>   that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
>   non-zero exit code.

Here is my code

**cli.js** 
used to parse the command line arguments to initialize the application by calling `node cli.js play`

```
const 
app = require('./app'),
yargs = require('yargs')

const flags = yargs.usage('$0: Usage <cmd> [options]')
.command({
    command: 'play',
    desc: 'play a 5 card draw game',
    builder: (yargs) => {
        return yargs.option('play', {
            alias: 'play',
            describe: 'shuffles deck and draws 5 random cards'
        })
    },
    handler: (argv) => { app.play() }
})
.help('help')
.argv
```

**app.js**

contains the methods used to run the application

```
const
    cards = require('deckofcards'),
    inquirer = require('inquirer')

const prompt = inquirer.createPromptModule();

const draw = (shuffle, n = 1) => {
    cards.deck(shuffle)
        .then(deck => cards.draw(deck.deck_id, n))
        .then(result => {
            console.log('-- CARDS --')
            result.cards.forEach(card => {
                console.log(`${card.value} of ${card.suit}`)
            })

            console.log('-- REMAING CARDS --')
            console.log(result.remaining)

            discardPrompt(result)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}


const discardPrompt = (result) => {      
    return prompt([{
        type: 'checkbox',
        message: 'select cards to throw away',
        name: 'cards',
        choices: () => {
            const cardsToThrow = []
            result.cards.forEach(card => {
                const obj = {number : card.value, face : card.suit}
                cardsToThrow.push(obj)
            }).then(
                choices.push(cardsToThrow)
            ).catch(err => console.log(err))
        }, 
        validate: () => function(answer) {
            if(answer.length < 1 && answer.length >= 5) {
                return "invalid selection, you must select at least 1 card and no more than 4"
            }       
        return true
        }  
    }])
}


const play = () => {
    draw(true, 5)
}

module.exports = {
    play
}
```

and this is the wrapper I created for the Deck of Cards API 
**index.js**

```
const
     config = require('./config'),
     superagent = require('superagent')


const _fetch = (command) => {
    return superagent.get(`${config.url}/${command}`)
        .then(response => response.body)
        .catch(error => error.response.body)
}

exports.deck = (shuffle) => {
    if (shuffle)
        return _fetch('deck/new/shuffle/?deck_count=1')
    else
        return _fetch('deck/new/')
}

exports.draw = (deck, n) => {
    return _fetch(`/deck/${deck}/draw/?count=${n}`)
}

exports.shuffle = (deck, n) => {
    return _fetch(`deck/${deck}/shuffle/`)
}
```

when I run it, I get the following output

```
node cli.js play
-- CARDS --
ACE of CLUBS
6 of CLUBS
7 of HEARTS
2 of SPADES
QUEEN of CLUBS
-- REMAING CARDS --
47
```

I will admit that I am fairly new to Javascript and coming from coding mostly in Java, the flow of things is a little abstract to me but any advice would be greatly appreciated